# ImageView emptied on subsequent activity launches

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

I'm using this AsyncTask to load an image from a URL and populate an ImageView with that image:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headerIV)).execute(imageURL);
```

and

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I noticed that whenever I background my app and relaunch the activity, the ImageViews are emptied. Various checks on the ImageViews show that they are null in `onCreate()`, and so if I want to show images again, I have to call the AsyncTask again, which eventually leads to out-of-memory exceptions. So, I'm wondering: Does the activity recycle/empty my ImageViews for some reasons on `onPause()` based on that code block I'm using?

Comment: You need to be aware of the activity life cycle. You'd be better off using an image loading library like Glide, Picasso and so on to do your loading for you.

Comment: You should use Picasso download image from url

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!!!

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView bmImage;
Bitmap mIcon11;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {


    try {
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(urls[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (result != null) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your app comes to foreground the onResume() is called and the views are generated again, so that can be the reason for the null values.
You can use onResume() for the same. (For more info check out Activity life cycle)
Also as suggested by others, you can use Picasso or Universal Image Loader or other libraries for ease.
To start with you can refer below links:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/
http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android
http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android